# Disable “swipe up to unlock” antifeature

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, android-11

Samsung Galaxy XCover 4s, stock ROM (work device), Android 11

To unlock the device, I first have to swipe up before I can enter the PIN. This is not so on my HTC Desire running LiquidSmooth 3.2 (kitkat) which directly displays the PIN screen.

Swiping up is a problematic gesture for me, especially on this huge device. How can I disable it so pressing the power button directly shows the PIN screen?

Comment: A bit off-topic comment. Your problem can be solved on a non-work device which has Xposed framework installed. GravityBox app offers Direct unlock feature which instantly shows the keyguard/credentials input view whenever screen turn on, and thus, removes the need to swipe up.

Comment: Yeah, that won’t help me on the work device though, which belongs to my employer and therefore must stay unrooted. But I appreciate the thought.