# Are there way to remove swipe up but have a number or a pattern lock on a modern Android

Tags: settings, lock-screens

Is it possible to remove swipe before entering a number code or drawing a pattern on modern versions of Android (10 for instance)?
*There is a similar question but it's about Android 3.*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the device rooted? GravityBox xposed module provides this feature.

Comment: Related question (and unanswered as of writing this) but for Android 11. See https://android.stackexchange.com/q/241715/96277